# $A\sin(\omega t - kx)$

Tags: trigonometry, physics, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

[image]

**My try:**

I assumed
$$y_1=A\sin(\omega t - kx)$$
$$y_2=A\sin(\omega t - kx+\pi)$$

$$y_1+y_2=0$$

So how do I find $2\pi \Delta t/ T$ when y = 0 ? I don't know if I do it right or not ! Can you please help me out a little bit.

I think
$$\pi = \frac{2\pi \Delta x}{\lambda}$$ which yields $\Delta x$ surely

Sorry to post this question here: I think mathematicians are great physicists also.

Comment: This should go to the physics stackexchange

Comment: thanks for your wonderful answer , i didnt know that

Comment: @KKZiomek For future occasions, this type of straight homework post, while it can be in topic on the maths site, is off-topic on Physics.